# Using R to calculate the mean of the part of a vector

Tags: r, tapply

My `R` vector looks like this:

```
vector <- c(3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, 7)
```

I want to use the function `tapply()` to calculate the `mean` of the `first 4 number` from the vector. How do I do it?

**What did I do?**

```
tapply(vector(1,4), mean)
```

but it seems like it does not work this way.

We **need** to use `tapply()` function.

Comment: @thelatemail my question requires `tapply()` but the `duplicate` you marked does not use `tapply()`

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should include the expected output. I assume ```2.5``` but your insistance on ```tapply()``` makes me question that assumption. Also, what do you get when you run ```vector(1,4)```?

Comment: @Cole I get this error: `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors` but I figured out the solution and `answered it below`.

Comment: `Solution: ` First categorize it.  `temp_vector = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)` and then `tapply(vector, temp_vector, mean)` which will give you `2.5, 5.0`. Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
mean(vector[1:4])
```